# R: Turn content of string into body of function

Tags: r, string, function

I wrote a function, which returns a function based on certain properties.
The problem is that I had to use "paste", which makes the returned object a string. Here an example of the returned object:

```
  the_problem <- "beta['v_p'] * 0.1 * ((3.99 * exp(-0.144 * time)) +   
                 (4.78 *  exp(-0.0111 * time))) + 0.1 * beta['ktrans_1'] * (3.99 * (exp(-
     beta['kep_1']* time) - exp(- 0.144 * time)) * (0.144 - 
     beta['kep_1'])**(-1) + (4.78 * (exp(- beta['kep_1'] * time)- exp(- 
     0.0111 * time)) * (0.0111 - beta['kep_1'])**(-1)))"
```

I would like to manipulate the object "the_problem" to make it usable as function. Something like:

```
dcemri_func <- function(beta){
  return(get.rid.of.string(the_problem))}
```

I already tried "as.function", but this does not work.
Any ideas?

Thanks and best whishes,

Chris

Comment: `body(dcemri_func) <- parse(text = the_problem)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `eval(parse(text = ..))`, i.e.:

```
 the_problem <- paste0('function(beta) ', the_problem)
 dcemri_func <- eval(parse(text = the_problem))
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your note! If the problem is solved, please consider to accept the solution by clicking on the tick mark next to the vote.